# Why do I get this error only when my application is in production?

Tags: express, nuxt.js, vercel

I am developing an application with NuxtJS and SSR, I am also using axios and auth modules. Everything works perfectly in localhost, but later when I upload the application to the host (Vercel) and try to log in, it gives me the 405 error. Does anyone know why this happens? The server is created with express

```
Error: Request failed with status code 405
        at t.exports (237de42.js:2)
        at t.exports (237de42.js:2)
        at XMLHttpRequest._.onreadystatechange (237de42.js:2)
```

This is my nuxt.config.js file:

```
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',
  ssr: true,
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head,
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '~/modules/api/index.js'
  ],
  env:{
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
  axios: {
    credentials: true,
    https: true,
    baseURL: 'https://www.encontrarhogar.com.ar/',
    init(axios) {
      axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    }
  },
  head: {
    title: 'Encontrar Hogar',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/normalize.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: "https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: "https://kit.fontawesome.com/57d52ad1ee.js", crossorigin: "anonymous" },
    ]
  },
  loading: {
    color: 'black',
    height: '8px',
    continuous: true
  },
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/index.css'
  ],
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'token'
        },
        user: {
          property: 'user'
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/server/api/usuarios/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data' },
          user: { url: '/server/api/usuarios/mi-perfil', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' },
          logout: { url: '/server/api/usuarios/logout', method: 'delete' }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: ['~/plugins/swiper.js'],
  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true
}
```

Comment: ```405 error``` appears on express backend? check cors settings or add cors middleware https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Nowhere in my backend am I returning the 405 code, the cors is enabled with the credentials activated. Also, it seems strange to me, because if it were for the cors, wouldn't it give the error in localhost as well?

Comment: The console shows me this warning, could it have something to do with it? The cookie "auth.strategy" is going to be rejected soon because it has the "<SameSite" attribute set to "none" or an invalid value, without the "secure" attribute. To know more about the "SameSite" attribute, read.